# How does X + X'.Y = X + Y?

Tags: logic

I don't know how I can split X + X'.Y up or apply any logic laws to manipulate it. These are the logic laws I am taught and I feel like I can apply a lot of them to it but either X bar or the "or" or "add" will get in the way.

[Logic laws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB8tu.png)

Comment: $$x+xy'=x(1+y)+x'y=x+y(x+x')$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
X+(X'Y) &\equiv (X+X')(X+Y)&\text{distributivity}\\
&\equiv T(X+Y)&\text{inverse}\\
&\equiv X+Y&\text{domination} 
\end{align}$$

$\text{You can use venn diagram also.}$

$X + (X'Y) =$ 
[image]

$X + Y =$

[image]